# How do I pull out a value for a specific entry in a array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I need to be able to pull out a specific value from an array to be able to use it in an IF statement to filter out data within a SQL. What my goal is to be able to do is to create something like this

```
if(obj !== undefined){ //do something} else { //do something else }
```

The reason why I need to do this is to know if there is an entry or not within the SQL and this was the only what I could think of doing that. To check if it returns any values when searching for it.

The code:

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM whitelisttest WHERE (identifier) = (?)", [messageArray[1]], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var person = JSON.stringify(result);
    obj = JSON.parse(person);
    test = obj.whitelisted;
    console.log(result);
    console.log(obj);
    console.log(person);
    console.log(test);
```

Console log result:

```
[ RowDataPacket { identifier: 'etanol', whitelisted: 3 } ]

[ { identifier: 'etanol', whitelisted: 3 } ]

[{"identifier":"etanol","whitelisted":3}]

undefined
```

---

The expected result is for the output that is currently undefined and that is called test in the code to be 3, and for the result to be etanol if I did.

```
test = obj.identifier
console.log(test)
```

EDIT:

Solution that helped me (missed the [0] when trying to do obj.whitelisted when it was supposed to be obj[0].whitelisted)

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM whitelisttest WHERE (identifier) = (?)", [messageArray[1]], function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var person = JSON.stringify(result);
             obj = JSON.parse(person);
             console.log(obj[0].whitelited)
```

Comment: no need to do `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`, whose are opposites method just do directly : `console.log(result[0].whitelited)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an array `console.log(Array.isArray(result) )` // => true

so your complete answer shoud be :

```
con.query( "SELECT * FROM whitelisttest WHERE (identifier) = (?)"
          , [messageArray[1]]
          , function (err, result)
            {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log(result[0].whitelisted)
              //...
```

no need to use `JSON.stringify` and `then JSON.parse`

```js
var obj = [ { identifier: 'etanol', whitelisted: 3 } ];


console.log(' obj[0].whitelisted => ', obj[0].whitelisted);  // => 3

var ref = 'whitelisted';

console.log(' obj[0][ref] => ', obj[0][ref]);  // => 3

console.log(' obj[0]["whiteliste"] => ', obj[0]['whitelisted']); // => 3
```

Comment: Well yes, but how I want to be able to use the SQL and not manually typing in the array.

Comment: not sure to understand, but JS can accept differents writing way to access json content .

 (I have changed my post to show them)

Comment: It helped check edit for solution. Thank you. Missed the [0]

Answer (score 0):

Because it's an array, you need to access the property `whitelisted` of the first element:

```js
var person = [{
  "identifier": "etanol",
  "whitelisted": 3
}]

console.log(person[0].whitelisted);
```

Comment: Well that would kill the puropse of using an SQL if I need to manualy go in and add the array.